# Can't echo newly Assigned value of Class Variable in PHP

Tags: php, class, oop, constructor

Here is my Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Reconstructing the Person Class</title>
      <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
    </head>
    <body>
      <p>
        <?php 
            class Person {
                public $isAlive = true;
                public $firstname;
                public $lastname;
                public $age;

                public function __construct() {
                    $this->firstname = "Umair";
                    $this->lastname = "Dongle";
                    $this->age = 23;
                }
            }
            $teacher = new Person("Matt","Zinger",34);
            $student = new Person("Hassan", "Naseer", 90);
            echo $teacher->age;
        ?>
      </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

This result should be 34 but I'm getting 23. Can someone explain this since i'm new to PHP still learning. and also if there is an alternative syntax for -> this wired thing then also tell me please.
Thanks

Comment: there are no parameters on your contructor

Comment: And you assign to variables same, hardcoded values on each time when you contruct new object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Ghost](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3859027/ghost) mentioned, you do not have any parameters in your constructor `__construct()`. Therefore PHP drops the arguments in favor of the hard coded values specified inside the constructor.

The following should work:

```
public function __construct($firstname, $lastname, $age) {
    $this->firstname = $firstname;
    $this->lastname = $lastname;
    $this->age = $age;
}
```

There is no alternative syntax to access a member of a class.

Answer (score 1):

You have to supply parameters to your constructor:

```
public function __construct($_f, $_l, $_a) {
    $this->firstname = $_f;
    $this->lastname = $_a;
    $this->age = $_a;
}
```

More in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php).